# export dataframe excel directly to sharepoint (or a web page)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I created a dataframe to jupyter notebook and I would like to export this dataframe directly to sharepoint as an excel file. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

As per the other answers, there doesn't seem to be a way to write a dataframe directly to SharePoint at the moment, but rather than saving it to file locally, you can create a BytesIO object in memory, and write that to SharePoint using the [Office365-REST-Python-Client](https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/).

```
from io import BytesIO

buffer = BytesIO()               # Create a buffer object
df.to_excel(buffer, index=False) # Write the dataframe to the buffer
buffer.seek(0)
file_content = buffer.read()
```

Referencing the example script [upload_file.py](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/upload_file.py), you would just replace the lines reading in the file with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way directly export pandas dataframe data to sharepoint but you can export your pandas data to excel and then upload the excel data to sharepoint

Export Covid data to Excel file

```
df.to_excel(r'/home/noh/Desktop/covid19.xls', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the SharePoint site as a network drive on your local computer and then use a file path that way. Here's [a link](https://collab365.community/map-a-sharepoint-document-library-as-a-network-drive/) to show you how to map the SharePoint to a network drive. From there, just select the file path for the drive you selected.

```
df.to_excel(r'Y:\Shared Documents\file_name.xlsx')
```