# Saving Pandas dataframe to SharePoint location as csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sharepoint

I want to save my transformed dataset to csv on SharePoint location.

Can anyone help with how to approach. I have gone through Libraries shareplum but they read data from local and then upload to SharePoint.

I want to save  pandas df directly to SharePoint as csv or excel file .

Comment: Were you able to achieve the requirement?

Comment: Thank you Rajalakshmi for the solution .I had requirement changed so was not able to test this . I will definitely try to test this soon and update you with result. Meanwhile could you suggest how can we possibly save the transformed data to  onedrive.

Comment: I answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69499249/5522007.
That solution uses the Office365-REST-Python-Client to upload a dataframe from memory to a location in SharePoint by converting the df to an io.BytesIO() object.

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar data transfer to load data from snowflake table to files in SharePoint using dataframe. To load the files to Sharepoint I'm using Shareplum package. The below code takes data from Snowflake table and writes to a dataframe, this is then processed as files to SharePoint folder.

```
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum.site import Version
import pandas as pd

#connecting to SharePoint folder
authcookie = Office365(server_url, username = Username,password=Password).GetCookies()
site = Site(site_url, version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
folder = site.Folder(Sharepoint_folder)

#creating a dataframe 'df' from sql
sql_query = '''SELECT * FROM "DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."TABLE" '''
df= pd.read_sql(sql_query,con_var) # con_var is a variable holding snowflake connection details

#uploading file from dataframe to SharePoint folder
filename = 'my_file_name.csv'
folder.upload_file(df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8'))
```

Let me know if this worked for you or else we can try for other alternatives