# Trying to save pandas dataframe as an excel file but getting import error

Tags: python, sharepoint, importerror, office365api

Im trying to save my pandas dataframe as an excel sheet in my sharepoint site using  Office365-REST-Python-Client API.

I referred to the below link
[Saving Pandas dataframe to SharePoint location as csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69499249/5522007)

where the user(Thanks to violet) says create a BytesIO object in memory, and write that to SharePoint using the Office365-REST-Python-Client.

Also, he told to refer to [upload file.py](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/files/upload_file.py)

I have made the changes suggested by him and this is how my code looks like,

```
import os
from io import BytesIO

from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from tests import test_user_credentials, test_team_site_url

ctx = ClientContext(test_team_site_url).with_credentials(test_user_credentials)

path = "../../data/report #123.xlsx"



buffer = BytesIO()               # Create a buffer object
df.to_excel(buffer, index=False) # Write the dataframe to the buffer
buffer.seek(0)
file_content = buffer.read()



list_title = "Documents"
target_folder = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(list_title).root_folder
name = os.path.basename(path)
target_file = target_folder.upload_file(name, file_content).execute_query()
print("File has been uploaded to url: {0}".format(target_file.serverRelativeUrl))
```

But im getting an import error **ImportError: cannot import name 'test_user_credentials' from 'tests'**

I'm not sure whether im missing any package. I tried to do `pip install tests` but it was not working.

I have already installed python office 365 rest api using `pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client`

I tried looking online also but was not able to find for this tests module.
Am I missing an package?Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
from tests import test_site_url, settings
```

the tests module is a Private module , don’t need to download form pip or pypi , you should download all folder like this

[image]

[image]

and your code will be find it

Comment: I downloaded this file and unzipped and placed it in my site-packages folder. But I'm getting the same error.