# How to upload Pandas dataframe to SharePoint List in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sharepoint, upload

I'm looking for ways to upload a dataframe to SharePoint list in Python. Options that I thought of are:

**Options:**

1. Save dataframe as BytesIO object and upload object to sharepoint list
2. Upload dataframe directly to sharepoint list

Either way, anyone can kindly share how can I achieve either of this in Python? And possibly, which would be the easier method of the two?

For option 1, I've found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61384887/export-dataframe-excel-directly-to-sharepoint-or-a-web-page) that creates a BytesIO object from a dataframe. But how do I upload the object as a sharepoint list?

For option 2, I have no idea on how to do it at all.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.